# Webpack use folder name instead of Url for public path

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack

I am using react and django. I am trying to use code-splitting in my components, so in my webpack.config.js I have this

```
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "frontend/static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].chunk.js",
    publicPath: "/frontend/static/frontend/"
  },
```

but when it requests it in the browser it goes to

```
/en/account/quiz/drug-abuse/frontend/static/frontend/2.chunk.js
```

instead of

```
static/frontend/2.chunk.js
```

my javascript files are located in my static folder for django but react routing starts at /en/, I am guessing that is why the confusion is happening.
Is there anyway to make the webpack file look for

```
http://domainblahblah.com/static/frontend/2,chunk.js
```

Comment: in your /dist `index.html` file (not the original, but the production one), there might be a line `2.chunk.js`. Take a look and see what is going on there, because I suspect it's using a relative link in your case, ex. `src="static/frontend/xxx"`. But it needs to be absolute link, ex. `src="/static/frontend/xxx". With `/`